# How to create a switch for a takeDamage method

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am somewhat new to coding in general, and I am currently using Netbeans with Java. I am trying to create a switch method that takes away shield depending on how much damage is dealt with by another character in the code. If the damage takes away more than the remaining shield, health must be taken away, and if there is no health left, a life must be taken away. After life is taken, the shield and health have to return to normal. I have been trying to figure this out for days. Any info with how to do this will be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: I don't think a switch statement would be appropriate, just a few subtractions and ifs

Comment: Should i do if if(shield > 0){
// do stuff
}
else{
health -= damage;
}

Comment: @beansmcgee something like `shield-=damage; if(shield<0){health+=shield; shield=0;}`

Comment: this is what i have so far ----- public void takeDamage(int damage) {
       if(this.shield = 0) {
             this.shield = 
         } else {

Comment: public void takeDamage(int damage) {
       if(damage > shield) {
            damage -= shield;
            shield = 0;
         } else {
           shield -= damage; 
       }

Comment: please [edit] your post to add that code so readers can understand the problem without reading the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
public void takeDamage(int damage){
    shield-=damage;
    if(shield < 0){
        health+=shield; //shield is negative,so subtracts leftover damage from health
        if(health <= 0){
            lives--;
            health=DEFAULT_HEALTH_VALUE; //replace with your own default values
            shield=DEFAULT_SHIELD_VALUE;
        }
    }
}
```